# SQL Java Data connection

Tags: java, sql

I having difficulty sequencing the class path for the jars, url for Microsoft SQL Express 2019 into a java method. I haven’t been able to connect the drivers to open and execute sql file within java module, the new JDBC Requirements is causing a run error. This also occurwhen running on access. Can some provided a thorough explanations so I can think of what I might have coded in the connection url.

Comment: Connection URL Sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I already look over the websites. I think I’m having hard time connecting with the current server

Comment: I keep getting the driver run error, it states the there isn’t suitable driver for driver manager, I was sure if I had to also login a driver in the control panel